# I'm very new to Python programming and have a question about python-docx: where is the function add_r() in paragraph.py defined?

Tags: python-docx

- add_r is called inside add_run in file paragraph.py

```
   def add_run(self, text=None, style=None):
        r = self._p.**add_r()**
        run = Run(r, self)
        if text:
            run.text = text
        if style:
            run.style = style
        return run
```

Answer (score 0):

It is added to the `docx.oxml.text.paragraph.CT_P` class by its metaclass in response to this declaration in the class definition:

```
class CT_P(BaseOxmlElement):
    """
    ``<w:p>`` element, containing the properties and text for a paragraph.
    """
    pPr = ZeroOrOne('w:pPr')
    r = ZeroOrMore('w:r')  # <--- this line causes the metaclass to create the .add_r() method
```

https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/blob/master/docx/oxml/text/paragraph.py#L16

Comment: Thank you very much, Scanny

Comment: @JohnSmith welcome to StackOverflow! Be sure to accept the answer that answers your question. This is how you acknowledge the respondent for taking the time to respond to your question :)